# How can I insert page breaks between groups in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-12

In selection expert options "I have set Keep Group Together,new page before,new page after" which makes sure a new page is set.

how can I make sure that a new group always forms on a new sheet of paper? Can this be done in the formula expert? 
right now it is coming in seperate page. i want a new organization employee list record in new page every time. How can i insert a page break after a organization employee list record is displayed.?
Just asking leading questions because I'm not familiar with what is possible with Crystal's formula editor.

Any tips are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: please can you clarify what you want to do? At the moment, it sounds as though what you want is what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark said in his comment, you already did it.  To find out what is possible with Crystal's formula editor, there is a list of functions at the top.  Select a function that interests you and press F1 for a decent set of help files.

[image]